# I have a nested if statement and the inside statement nullifies the outter

Tags: python, if-statement

```
board=[[1,0,8,5,12,16,24],[7,0,6,2,20,4,18],[13,0,9,10,22,23,17],[19,0,11,3,14,15,21]]

def move():
while board[0][6]!= 0 and board[1][6]!=0 and board[2][6]!=0 and board[3][6]!=0: 
    user_choice= int(raw_input('>'))
    for lists in board:
        for i in range(len(lists)):
            if lists[i]== user_choice-1 and lists[i+1]==0:
                lists[i+1]= user_choice
                print print_board(board)                    
                for a in board:
                    for i in range(len(a)):
                        if a[i]==user_choice:
                            a[i]=0
                            print print_board(board)
```

I am making a game where the user inputs a number (user_choice).  The program will find the number 1 smaller than user_choice.  Say the user picks 8, the game will find the number 7 on the board and if the number after 7 is 0 the program swaps the location of the 0 and the 8.

The code I have works except when the second if statement runs the output undoes the first if statement

here is a typical output for user_choice=8:

```
[[1,0,8,5,12,16,24],[7,8,6,2,20,4,18],[13,0,9,10,22,23,17],[19,0,11,3,14,15,21]]
None
[[1,0,8,5,12,16,24],[7,0,6,2,20,4,18],[13,0,9,10,22,23,17],[19,0,11,3,14,15,21]]
None
[[1,0,0,5,12,16,24],[7,0,6,2,20,4,18],[13,0,9,10,22,23,17],[19,0,11,3,14,15,21]]
```

The first output replaced the 0 after the 7 with an 8.
The second output seems to show the initial board.
The third output replaces the 8 in the initial board with a 0.

I want one output that both replaces the 0 after the 7 with an 8 and replaces the initial 8 with a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order in which you edit the board. First replace any other '8's by zero, then change the zero after a 7 to an 8.

```
    for i in range(len(lists)-1):
        if lists[i]== user_choice-1 and lists[i+1]==0:  
            for a in board:
                for j in range(len(a)):
                    if a[j]==user_choice:
                        a[j]=0
                        print print_board(board)  
            lists[i+1]= user_choice
            print print_board(board)
```

I've also used different variables i, and j and tried to avoid an `IndexError`, if `i+1 == len(lists)`

Order of operations is significant here. If you start by replacing the 0 following a 7 by an 8, and then replace all 8s by 0s, the overall effect is to replace the 0 following a 7 by a 0.  Not what you want

If you change the other 8s to zeros first, and then change the zero after a 7 to an 8, the overall effect is what you want.

I think that there may still be bugs here.. For example, can there be more than one 7 followed by an 0? What happens if there is a 7 followed by an 8 already on the board? Solving these bugs means thinking very carefully about exactly what you want the computer to do, since it won't do the thinking for you!

Comment: Can you explain why the order is important here?

Comment: @tdammon The ordering is important because you first replaced the 7 with an 8, but then replaced all 8s with 0s.  I have not tried this solution but I would be wary of it switching out 8s when a valid (7, 0) pair was never found.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution in the world, but here is mine:

```
board = [
            [1, 0, 8, 5, 12, 16, 24],
            [7, 0, 6, 2, 20, 4, 18],
            [13, 0, 9, 10, 22, 23, 17],
            [19, 0, 11, 3, 14, 15, 21]
]

def print_board():
    for row in board:
        print " ".join("{:2}".format(x) for x in row)

while any(row[6] for row in board):
    print_board()
    user_choice = int(raw_input('-> '))
    replace_match = False
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        pairs = zip(row, row[1:])
        for j, pair in enumerate(pairs):
            if pair == (user_choice - 1, 0):
                board[i][j+1] = user_choice
                replace_match = (i, j+1)
                print pair
                break
    else:
        if replace_match:
            for i, row in enumerate(board):
                board[i] = [x if (x != user_choice or (i, j) == replace_match) else 0 for j, x in enumerate(row)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find things easier if you break the problem into smaller functions. Here a simple example:

```
board = [[1,0,8,5,12,16,24],[7,0,6,2,20,4,18],[13,0,9,10,22,23,17],[19,0,11,3,14,15,21]]

# See if item is in lst. If so, return xy location
def in_list(item, lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        for j in range(0, len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] == item:
                return i, j
    return -1,-1

def print_board():
    for i in board:
        for j in i:
            print j, ' ',
        print

def game_over():
    return board[0][6] == 0 and board[1][6] == 0 and board[2][6] == 0 and board[3][6] == 0

while (False == game_over()):
    print_board()
    user_choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    # ux,uy are co-ords of user choice
    ux, uy = in_list(user_choice, board)
    if (-1 != ux):
        # mx,my are co-ords of user choice+1
        mx, my = in_list(user_choice - 1, board)
        if (-1 != mx):
            if (0 == board[mx][my + 1]):
                board[ux][ux] = 0
                board[mx][my + 1] = user_choice
```